# Dimensionality Reduction on Mixed Data

Tags: categorical-data, references, dataset, dimensionality-reduction, importance

If you have a dataset with not only numerical data, but also categorical and boolean. How do you approach doing dimensionality reduction to this dataset. The standard algorithms only work with numerical data.

Anyone know of good sources to read about this sort of thing also appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do dimension reduction? How many columns are numerical, categorical and boolean? Also note that you can perform some dimension reduction techniques on boolean data by converting TRUE to $1$ and FALSE to $0$

Comment: its a 50-50 split. i need to work out which what are the most important features in the data

Comment: Important in what regard? What are you trying to actually do with the data. Try to put some proper context into the question and a description of the data and any research questions you have

Comment: When represented as random variables--which is always possible--these *are* numerical data and all algorithms work with them.